# What is this error mean" expression must have pointer-to-class type"?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm a beginner, I Make a treap tree , I make a class type and pointer to this `class` , when I used "`this` keyword" to point to next element this appeared

> compiler error: "expression must have pointer-to-class type"

```
 this->right->search_el(k,p);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you apply `operator ->` to a non-pointer type. You probably want:

```
this->right.search_el(k,p);
```

Since `this` is a pointer, `right` seems like the only candidate that is not a pointer. In C++, you access members of a class through `.` if you have an instance or `->` if you have a pointer to an instance.